# onTimer() not trigger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have an issue with OnTimer() function of Modeless Dialog window (who is a child window of CDialogEx window) ,it refuse to trigger.

When i make the dialog Modal with CDialog::DoModal() function its working fine. 
But i want Modeless Dialog.

Could you explain me what happen here .

I try to be accurate. The ClogoDlg Dialog is a SPLASH window of the application .It showing for 3 minutes, in the middle the program running Lengthy Operation. The SPLASH window displays a duration of time. Therefor i want the OnTimer() function.

Thanks .

my code is:

```
BOOL Clotto2Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  ClogoDlg* pdlg=new ClogoDlg();
  pdlg->Create(GetDesktopWindow());
  //pdlg->DoModal();
  pdlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

My ClogoDlg.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClogoDlg.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(ClogoDlg, CDialog)


ClogoDlg::ClogoDlg(CWnd* pParent )  : CDialog(ClogoDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}


ClogoDlg::~ClogoDlg()
{
  KillTimer(m_nTimer);
}


BOOL ClogoDlg::Create(CWnd* pParentWnd)
{
  // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

  return CDialog::Create(ClogoDlg::IDD,pParentWnd);

}
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ClogoDlg, CDialog)
  ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
  ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK()
  ON_WM_PAINT()
  ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void ClogoDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
  Invalidate();

  CDialog::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void ClogoDlg::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

  CDialog::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);
}



BOOL ClogoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialog::OnInitDialog();

  // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
  m_nTimer = SetTimer(2, 1000, NULL);

  return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
              // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}


BOOL ClogoDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

  return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}


void ClogoDlg::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
                   // TODO: Add your message handler code here
                   // Do not call CDialog::OnPaint() for painting messages
  CTime timeNow;
  timeNow = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
  CString str;
  str.Format(L"%3d:%2d:%2d", timeNow.GetHour(), timeNow.GetMinute(), timeNow.GetSecond());
  dc.TextOut(10,10, str);

}

void ClogoDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
  Invalidate();

  CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

And my ClogoDlg.h

```
#pragma once
#include "resource.h" 
class ClogoDlg:public CDialog
{
  DECLARE_DYNAMIC(ClogoDlg)
  public:
  enum{IDD=IDD_LOGO};
  ClogoDlg();
  ~ClogoDlg();
  BOOL Create(CWnd * pParent = NULL);
  CTime timer;
  int m_nTimer;

  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
  afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
  afx_msg void OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
  virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
  virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
  afx_msg void OnPaint();
  afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent);
};
```

Comment: And what is your Question? You already have a Create function... did you ever used it? Remember that a timer can only be called when there is still a message loop running!

Comment: Tel me what to do in order trigger the OnTimer() function.

Comment: You need a message loop...

Comment: OK i put the message loop after the dialog Show(). But a want the program to keep running outside the loop.Where i muste to put it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Give us a broader picture. Read this: http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear.
I try to be accurate.
The ClogoDlg Dialog is a SPLASH window of the application .It showing for 3 minutes,
in the middle the program running Lengthy Operation.
The SPLASH window displays a duration of time.
Therefor i want the OnTimer() function.

Comment: @KostasProntis please [edit] your querstion and put all clarifications _there_